# Internet Browser works, but not Steam, Origin, Hearthstone etc

Tags: windows-networking

So, I think my problem is apparent from the question itself. I can access websites from my browser of choice (Chrome in this case) but Steam, Origin, Hearthstone etc does not work. Skype does seem to work however. I'm fairly computer savvy but network issues always seem to stump me. It all worked fine yesterday, firewall is off. Any tips at all would be very appreciated

Comment: So you can acces e.g. steampowered.com over browser but not over Steam' client, right?

Comment: exactly. When I try to log in with the client it tells me it can't connect... offline mode... etc. Same with Hearthstone.

Answer (score 0):

For Steam's part of your question you can try [this solution](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/666826703761549038/):

- Close Steam application
- Backup (make a copy) the **“…\STEAM\userdata”** folder.
- ...
- Rename or delete the “…\STEAM\userdata” folder (it is into the main folder that steam creates when it is installed.)
- Run again the Steam.exe or your preferred shortcut, to start Steam as you do normally. At my case, steam started normally, I could change-and-save the settings in Friends tab, and both Online and offline modes are now working correctly after numerous Exit-Start-Exit-Start tests of steam application. … But, many of my saved games were NOT listed on the relevant games Load-game screens. (!Close to Hart Attack! The saves ware still on my harddrive, but steam could not see them. Same problem with the ‘cloud’ steam application that I suggest you have deactivated, since if your saved games reach a MB volume, it could start deleting some of them)
- Close Steam
- Go to the “…\STEAM” folder.

In my case, steam had created a new ‘userdata’ subfolder, with some things inside, including a ‘config’ folder. Copy-paste allowing to override, the subfolders from your ‘userdata’ backup into the new ‘userdata’ now inside your Steam folder, **EXCEPT OF THE ‘config’ SUBFOLDER** !!

Comment: Curious, it worked until I reinstated the back-up, bar the config as instructed. Now it doesn't work >_>. Will tweak a bit, see if I can make it work

Comment: would seems it only works the first time I remove userdata, regardless of whether I reinstate the back-up or not =/